# Change customer Address form City field - Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

i'm trying to change `city` text field in to `drop down list` (front end my account address).i want user to select the city from the drop down list.that list should load from the database `city` table.

**address-form.tpl** file contain that address form and those textfields.but how can i change textfield in to drop down?

**address-form.tpl**

```
<section class="form-fields">
      {block name='form_fields'}
        {foreach from=$formFields item="field"}
          {block name='form_field'}
            {form_field field=$field}
          {/block}
        {/foreach}
      {/block}
    </section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit Front Address form - Prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248651/how-to-edit-front-address-form-prestashop)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model City and database table for this you can go to your `Dashboard -> International -> Locations -> Countries`, then click on the list to edit your country and under the label `Address format` you can find address form fields, just make field `city` similar to `Country:name` - replace `city` with `City:name`. If you have correct `City` model and database table for this then you should see dropdown with your cities. I'm not pretty sure if it will save city name or ID to address `city` field in database, so you must check this and possibly make some magic to replace ID's with names in dropdown ;)