# How to edit Front Address form - Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to use drop down list instead of textbox for 'City' field.(Like country list).I tried to edit `address-form.tpl` file.but it's contain smarty values.I don't know which .tpl/Controller i want to edit.

**address-form.tpl**

```
<section class="form-fields">
      {block name='form_fields'}
        {foreach from=$formFields item="field"}
          {block name='form_field'}
            {form_field field=$field}
          {/block}
        {/foreach}
      {/block}
    </section>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to create looooong list of all cities, villages and settlements all over the world in single drop down menu? What if there will be one missing? Will you have alternative text field?

Comment: I have list of cities in sri lanka.i want to show them on that city drop down.also i have only sri lanka in my country list.

Comment: ok, single country + list of it's cities make sense.

Comment: looks like `authentication.tpl` in your theme directory

Answer (score 2):

finally i got a solution

1) add form type to city field 
`classes/form/CustomerAddressFormatter.php`

```
if ($field === 'city') {
                    $formField->setType('select');
                    $formField->setType('citySelect');
                    $formField->setRequired(true);

                    $loc=new Location();         //load data from db
                    $result=$loc->getLocations();

                    foreach ($result as $value) {
                        $formField->addAvailableValue(
                            $value['area'],
                            $value['area']
                        );
                    }
            }
```

2) edit .tpl file
`themes/yourtheme/templates/_partials/form-fields.tpl`

```
{elseif $field.type === 'citySelect'}

          <select
            class="form-control form-control-select chosen-select"
            name="{$field.name}"
            {if $field.required}required{/if}
          >
            <option value disabled selected>{l s='-- please choose --' d='Shop.Forms.Labels'}</option>
            {foreach from=$field.availableValues item="label" key="value"}
              <option value="{$value}" {if $value eq $field.value} selected {/if}>{$label}</option>
            {/foreach}
          </select>
```